# How to get two cursor in java with JPA?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, stored-procedures

I have a problem when stored return two cursor. My code:

```
        StoredProcedureQuery sp = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("UORDER.GetAllItemInOrder",Item.class,Loyalty.class);
        sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter("i_order_id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter("i_merchant_id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter("o_cur_line_items", Void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
        sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter("o_cur_loyalty", Void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
        sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter("o_count_item", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter("o_total_item", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter("o_data", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        sp.registerStoredProcedureParameter("o_code", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        sp.setParameter("i_order_id", orderId);
        sp.setParameter("i_merchant_id", merchantId);
        sp.execute();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Item> items = sp.getResultList();


        for(Item item : items){
            System.out.println(item);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Loyalty> lstLoyalties = sp.getResultList();
        for(Loyalty loy : lstLoyalties){
            System.out.println(loy);
        }
```

I only get cursor items. Could you tell me where my mistake and fix it? 
Thanks all.

Comment: What is the code of stored procedure?

Comment: Thanks @Kamil 4 your reply. I fixed my problem, i missing select ID of Loyalty.